# How to loop around all id in "ids" array asynchronously and return data for all ids?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I am new to typescript and I am working on a project where I need to populate all the fields in `GridModel` interface by querying data. I have the below code after several attempt which works fine.
In the below code, I pick single `id` from `ids` array and then make the necessary call to get all those fields and populate `GridModel` interface. Below code only works for single id which I pick as first index from `ids` array.

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import {
  useGetClientOrdersByItemQuery,
  useGetClientOrdersQuery,
  useGetClientOrderLineByLineIdLazyQuery,
} from '../../../../hooks/static/use-get-client-orders-by-item'

interface GridModel {
  purchaseOrderId: string | undefined,
  lineNumber: string | undefined,
  warehouse: string | undefined,
  startShipDate: string | undefined,
}

export const useViewPurchaseOrderData = (ids: string[]) => {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState<GridModel[]>([])
  const [fetchLines, { loading: linesLoading }] = useGetClientOrderLineByLineIdLazyQuery()
  const { data, loading } = useGetClientOrdersByItemQuery({
    variables: { itemId: Number(ids[0]) },
    skip: !ids[0],
  })

  const poIds = (data?.getPurchaseOrdersByItem?.map((p) => p?.purchaseOrderId)
    .filter((poid): poid is number => Boolean(poid)) ?? [])
  const poidToLines = useMemo(() => data?.getPurchaseOrdersByItem
    ?.map((p) => ({ orderId: p?.purchaseOrderId, lines: p?.lineIds })), [data])

  const { data: purchaseData, loading: purchaseLoading } = useGetClientOrdersQuery({
    variables: { poIds, count: poIds.length, offset: 0 },
    skip: !poIds.length,
  })
  const purchaseOrders = purchaseData?.getPurchaseOrders?.purchaseOrders

  useEffect(() => {
    const lineRequests = poidToLines?.flatMap((p) => p?.lines?.map((lineId) => fetchLines({
      variables: {
        purchaseOrderId: p?.orderId ?? 0,
        purchaseOrderLineId: lineId ?? 0,
      },
    }).then((result) => ({
      result: result.data?.getPurchaseOrderLineByLineId,
      poId: p?.orderId,
    })))).filter(Boolean) as Promise<any>[]

    if (purchaseOrders && purchaseOrders.length && lineRequests && lineRequests.length) {
      Promise.all(lineRequests).then((lines) => {
        const mapped: GridModel[] = lines.map((line) => {
          const order = purchaseOrders.find((po) => po?.id === line.poId.toString())
          return {
            purchaseOrderId: order?.id ?? undefined,
            lineNumber: line?.result.lineId ?? undefined,
            warehouse: order?.site?.name ?? undefined,
            startShipDate: order?.expectedShipDate ?? undefined,
          }
        }) ?? []
        setGridData(mapped)
      })
    }
  }, [poidToLines, purchaseOrders])

  return {
    data: gridData,
    loading: loading || purchaseLoading || linesLoading,
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement**

Is there any way where I can loop around all ids in `ids` array either asynchronously or sequentially inside `useViewPurchaseOrderData` function? And for each single id, I will do exact same thing which I am already doing in above code? So idea is -

- Iterate all id from `ids` array either asynchronously or sequentially. For each id do exact above thing and then once we have data for all id return everything back.

Is this possible to do by any chance in typescript. I am from Java, C# background so having hard time figuring out on how to do this in Typescript.

Comment: It seems the problem is with `useGetClientOrdersByItemQuery` accepting only a single id. The problem is less to do with typescript and more than you cannot loop hook calls in Reactjs. Can you show us the code of *use-get-client-orders-by-item*?

Comment: Here is the [code](https://pastebin.com/XV4s8dyN) for that. I have a graphql query which is what it is making these calls into. I generate the ref pastebin code by running `npm run codegen` after adding my graphql query. @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi So you are saying, I cannot do for each loop here in my above code in the question and run each id in parallel?

Comment: You cannot put a loop around the `useGetClientOrdersByItemQuery()` call, at least. See https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/178 https://stackoverflow.com/q/59938677/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/68281221/1048572 for possible approaches. The ideal solution would obviously exposing an API that accepts an array of ids.

Comment: When you say ideal solution - you mean having a graphql query that accepts an array of ids right so that it works as it is without looping around it. @Bergi

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Also it should need only a single http request then.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. But I am not sure I am allowed to touch graphql query and update those so I need to figure out a way to do this on the frontend unfortunately. @Bergi

Comment: If you're not sure, try nonetheless - I'm certain that the backend team will be happy to provide that query instead of having your frontend run many parallel requests at once

Comment: I already asked them, they are asking me to do this on frontend. Not sure why.

Comment: There is all sorts of bad here. Looping a query on the client is terrible. You should also run `useGetClientOrderLineByLineIdLazyQuery` and `useGetClientOrdersByItemQuery` as a single query or create a single query that returns the totality of what you need. Your back-end team needs a talking to.